# How to set the last tab default in jquery Ul tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I Use this [Tutorial](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/) for my tabs.

Need to set the last tab active default

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have specific reasons to stick with that code (which in my opinion is pretty convoluted) I'd use the code that's show on the [JQueryUI homepage](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default). Basically, the html for the tabs will look like

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">T1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">T2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">T3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And activating the last tabs will become very simple, [see the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active): A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs(  
     {
        active: -1
     }
    );
  });
```

You see how little code is really needed?

Comment: Unfortunately not works for me ! Maybe I do something wrong ، Is possible you edit my code please ?

Comment: Sorry no, but I put the demo, based on the official demo code, in a nice jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/gLkzmp99/

Comment: thanks a lot @fvu , I replace JQueryUI with my method and problem solved <3